# Rails Active Record fuzzy-search Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.2

I have a Postgresql array column in my Rails app. These are, as far as I can tell, stored as long strings.

To search this column (`Place#name`), I've implemented the following methods in a module that I include like so:

```
class Place
  include ActiveRecord::MetaExt::ArrayAccessor
  array_accessor :name, :category
end
```

and define like so:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module MetaExt
    module ArrayAccessor

      module ClassMethods

        def array_accessor(*symbols)
          symbols.each do |singular|

            plural = singular.to_s.split("_").join(" ").pluralize.split(" ").join("_")

            # These two instance-level methods not super relevant to the question
            class_eval do 
              define_method("add_#{singular}") do |arg|
                send( "#{plural}=", (send(plural) + Array(arg)).uniq )
              end

              define_method(singular) do
                send(plural).first
              end
            end

            metaclass.instance_eval do 
              define_method("without_#{singular}") do
                where("? = '{}'", plural)
              end

              define_method("with_#{singular}") do |arg=nil|
                if arg.blank?
                  where.not("? = '{}'", plural)
                else
                  where("? = ANY (#{plural})", arg.is_a?(Array) ? arg.first : arg)
                end
              end
            end

          end
        end
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There are a couple of issues with this.

1) in the `with_name` (literally, `with_#{field}`) method, I'm only ever searching for the first name in the array given. I'd love to be able to search for all places containing ANY of those names. Having trouble figuring this out, though. Any ideas?

2) I'd love to be able to do fuzzy matching -- so that a search for "Barbeque Place" would grab a place with the name "The Barbecue Place". Took a look at the [Textacular gem](https://github.com/textacular/textacular), but I can't seem to adapt it to Array columns.

Any ideas how to make this work -- especially in a generalizable way?